# What is the time complexity(in big O notation) given the following code and why?

Tags: computational-complexity

The code provide below is number of divisors using prime factorization.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    vector<int> primes; // we'll preload primes once at the beginning
    int countDivisor(int n) {
      int divisor = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
        if (n % primes[i] == 0) {
          int cnt = 1;
          while (n % primes[i] == 0) {
            n /= primes[i];
            cnt++;
          }
          // add the number of times each prime divides n
          divisor += cnt;
        }
      }
      return divisor;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck, what did you try?

Comment: I want time complexity of this code.

Comment: I understand that, what did you try to solve this problem? If we know where you got stuck, we know how to best help you

Comment: I am trying to determine the time complexity of this code.But i do not understand it.

Comment: What do you not understand, the concept of time-complexity or this code?

Comment: Yes. I do not understand the concept of time-complexity.of this code.

Comment: Do you understand the general concept of time-complexity? Have you ever determined the time-complexity of other code?

Comment: I can determine the time-complexity of other code.But i can not to determine the time-complexity above code.

Comment: Ok, why not? What parts of this code make it difficult?

Comment: if the value of n=1000000.How many times will for loop?

Comment: Does the for-loop depend on n?

Comment: Sorry! I got answer.Thanks...

Comment: You're welcome. This is the reason we ask you to write what you tried in your question. In the end I only had to ask one simple question and then you could do the rest of the work yourself. That teaches you far more than just giving you the answer